# how do i make sword work with enemy collider

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision

here is my current code:

```
public GameObject enemy;


void OnCollisionEnter(UnityEngine.Collision collisionInfo)
{
    if (collisionInfo.collider.tag == "sword")
    {
        Debug.Log("works");
        enemy.SetActive(false);

    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("doesnt work");
    }
}
```

i have attached this to the enemy and also i tried a different script attached to the sword

```
 void OnTriggerStay(Collider col)
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
    {

        if (col.GetComponent<Collider>().tag == "enemy")
        {

            Destroy(col.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

both codes don't work, it seems that the problem isnt with the sword collision cus i have also added the tag to another gameobject and it doesnt work. i looked online but havent found anything that works so fat

Answer (score 0):

update: it seems that i have forgot you need a rigid body for collision detection. simple mistake but it made my code not work!

Answer (score 0):

For collision enter to work, both the sword and the enemy colliders need to have the "IsTrigger" box **unticked**.

For on triggerstay is the opposite, both need to have that box ticked.

Basically, Triggers do not collide they call that OnTriggerEnter function, while non-triggers use the OnCollisionEnter.